# install.packages() not working on R-Portable-Mac with electron-quick-start

Tags: r, installation, shiny, electron

I want to create a standalone app from my shiny app in R. My shiny app works correctly and I have followed the instructions in this link https://github.com/COVAIL/electron-quick-start/ I have been able to create the example app it is in the folder provided by COVAIL.

The problem comes when I try to install the required packages for my real app in shiny. I open the R-Portable.Mac/bin R executable and try to install the different packages I need (for example ggplot2). The thing is it appears the error message shown in the image

[image]

I tried installing rlang itself but it is not being installed. I have used .libPaths() to make sure the path is ok and it is. Can it be that the Portable-Mac-R is an old version and that is the reason why the packages are not being installed? I have also read that people were having issues with packages that required compilation.

As an example I could install dplyr but ggplot2 and shiny busy not.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Edited: The output when I try to install ggplot2 (if I write no the land message won't appear but it is not installed)

[image]

and this is the whole output when trying to install rlang

[image]

Comment: Is that all the output you get? Usually the exact error reason is included high up in the output. What is the full output when you try to just install `rlang`?

Comment: I have added to the question the outputs of both install.packages()

Comment: Have you figured this out? :)